# Why is My Python Turtle Screen not responding

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a collision detection system between a turtle and another turtle's line. The problem is that whenever i run the program, the turtle screen does not respond.I am using Pycharm and Python. Please Help!

```
import turtle
Screen = turtle.Screen()
P1 = turtle.Turtle()
P2 = turtle.Turtle()
Screen.screensize(100, 100)
x1 = []
x2 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []
P1.penup()
P1.setheading(180)
P2.setheading(90)
P1.goto(100, 50)
P2.penup()
P2.goto(50, 0)
P2.pendown()
P1.pendown()
n = 0
Num = 0
XC = P2.position()[0]
YC = P2.position()[1]
x1.append(XC)
y1.append(YC)
while Num == 0:
    XC = P2.position()[0]
    YC = P2.position()[1]
    x1[n] = XC
    y1[n] = YC
    if P1.heading() is 180:
        XC = P2.position()[0]
        YC = P2.position()[1]
        x2[n] = XC
        y2[n] = YC
        P1.position()
        XC1 = P1.position()[0]
        YC1 = P1.position()[1]
        for x in range(0, n):
            for z in range(x1.index(x), x2.index(x)):
                if abs(z-YC1)<10:
                    print("Found")
        P2.forward(1)
        P1.forward(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with that code. A major one is this line:

```
if P1.heading() is 180:
```

The `is` operator tests identity, i.e., it's  True if two expressions  evaluate to the same object. You should not use it to test if two expressions have the same value. In this case, `P1.heading()` returns the `float` object with a value of 180.0, so there's no way it could be the same object as the integer object with value 180. Thus your `if` block is never entered. And since the main commands that move the turtles are at the end of the `if` block, the turtles don't move once you enter the `while` loop.

Also, you are using `n` to index into your lists, but you never update `n` from zero, so all of the coordinates that you want to save are getting written into the first items of the lists.

However, if you *did* update `n` you'd run into another problem: you'd be attempting to index list items that don't exist, since `x1` and `y1` are of length one, and  `x2` and `y2` are of length zero.

Anyway, here's a simplified version of your code that does update the lists correctly, and does simple collision detection. It only detects exact collision, not approximate collision, but it should get you going in the right direction.

```
import turtle

Screen = turtle.Screen()
Screen.screensize(100, 100)

P1 = turtle.Turtle()
P2 = turtle.Turtle()

x1 = []
x2 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []

P1.penup()
P1.setheading(180)
P2.setheading(90)
P1.goto(100, 50)
P2.penup()
P2.goto(50, 0)
P2.pendown()
P1.pendown()

while True:
    print(P1.heading() is 180)
    XC = P2.position()[0]
    YC = P2.position()[1]
    x2.append(XC)
    y2.append(YC)

    XC = P1.position()[0]
    YC = P1.position()[1]
    x1.append(XC)
    y1.append(YC)

    if XC in x2 and YC in y2:
        print("Found")

    P2.forward(1)
    P1.forward(0.5)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Thank you, got it woking

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code.

First,

```
if P1.heading() is 180:
```

should be

```
if P1.heading() == 180:
```

In your loop you don't change your `Num` var.

You are trying to access an index that was not defined

```
    x2[n] = XC
    y2[n] = YC
```

Your logic doesn't make much sense in that for loop either.

Here, I made some corrections and I included a timer so you can see how your turtles are moving. This should help you to visualize what you are doing

```
import time
import turtle
Screen = turtle.Screen()
P1 = turtle.Turtle()
P2 = turtle.Turtle()
Screen.screensize(100, 100)
P1.penup()
P1.setheading(180)
P2.setheading(90)
P1.goto(100, 50)
P2.penup()
P2.goto(50, 0)
P2.pendown()
P1.pendown()
time.sleep(1)
n = 100
if P1.heading() == 180:
    for x in range(0, n):
        print(P1.position())
        print(P2.position())
        if abs(P1.position()[1] - P2.position()[1]) > 10:
            time.sleep(.3)
            P2.forward(1)
            P1.forward(.5)
        else:
            print('Found')
            break
```